# jq parsing from kubectl -ojsonpath output for annotations that are json

Tags: json, jq, kubectl, jsonpath

I have a lot of outputs from kubectl get XXXX -ojsonpath and I am using jq to parse and making things easy to read.  I am trying to find a way to parse and expand annoations if its an json object.

Currently I am writing out the annotations as (looped on the number of array)

```
jq -r '.items['${i}'].metadata.annotations | (to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)") | select(length >0)'
```

And I can see that sometimes some annotation is just a value and at other times its json.  I want to be able to expand out the json annotations to make it more readable

expand out the json. for example some of the annotations look like

```
test.bob.k8s.elastic.co/token=622fb4bd-e5f9-46e5-a73b-80b9d0fad43a
kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"agent.k8s.elastic.co/v1alpha1","kind":"Agent","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"test-agent","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"daemonSet":{"podTemplate":{"spec":{"automountServiceAccountToken":true,"containers":[{"command":["bash","-c","#!/usr/bin/env bash\nset -e\nif [[ -f /mnt/test-internal/test-association/default/bob/certs/ca.crt ]]; then\n  cp /mnt/test-internal/test-association/default/bob/certs/ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates\n  update-ca-certificates\nfi\n/usr/bin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint -e\n"],"name":"agent"}],"securityContext":{"runAsUser":0},"serviceAccountName":"test-agent"}}},"testServerRef":{"name":"test-server"},"testRef":{"name":"bob"},"mode":"test","version":"1.10.2"}}
```

I want to expand out kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration and other annotations that are json

Comment: You need to share the output of `kubectl get XXXX -ojsonpath` for us to be able to help you properly

Comment: You may need to elaborate on what you meant by `expand out the json`.

Comment: The length of the string interpolation containing a literal `=` will almost certainly be greater than 0, so the last filter step looks redundant

Comment: Without your JSON input to `jq`, I can only guesstimate what it looks like.  And I don't know what you would consider _"making things easy to read"_, but does this [jqplay.org example](https://jqplay.org/s/q7tAl1YLK7r) give you some ideas?